# How to make a child directive "$watch" the parent scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have a child directive listen to changes on the parent directive scope; however, "$watch" is not doing the trick. I feel like I am missing something very simple.

The premise of the code is to listen to select changes and get a property off the object and pass this to the child directive. I am using scope.$parent.$watch but this is not working. Any ideas?

```
/*
** method - fnDirective 
** desc - this is the main directive for the select/un select all
*/
function fnDirective(){
    return {
        restrict : "AE",
        replace : true,
        template : '\
            <div class="modal-form-wrapper">\
                <div class="form-control">\
                    <label for="attribute-filter">Selection Set Attribute</label>\
                    <select id="attribute-filter" name="attribute-filter">\
                        <option value="0">None</option>\
                        <option ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{ option.id }}" ng-selected="option.is_selected">{{ option.name }}</option>\
                    </select>\
                </div>\
                <list-attribute-options selections="selections"></list-attribute-options>\
            </div>\
        ',
        scope : {
            options : "=",
            selections : "="
        },
        link : function( scope, elem, attrs ){

            //on select change get the attribute selections
            elem.find( "select" ).on( "change", function( vent ){
                var select, option, attribute_id, selections;                   
                select = angular.element( this );
                option = select.find( "option:selected" );      
                attribute_id = parseInt( option.val() );    
                //get the selections off array      
                scope.selections = _.first( 
                    _.where( scope.options, { id : attribute_id }) 
                ).selections;
            });

        }

    };
}
/*
** method - fnListAttributeOptions 
** desc - list out the selections based on the selected attribute
*/
function fnListAttributeOptions(){
    return {
        restrict : "AE",
        replace : true,
        template : '\
            <div>\
                <ul class="list-form-options">\
                    <li ng-repeat="selection in selections">\
                    </li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>\
        ',
        scope : {
            selections : "="
        },
        link :  function( scope, elem, attrs ){
            scope.$parent.$watch( "selections", function( new_value, old_value ){
                cl( new_value, old_value );
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get you to try:
    `$scope.$parent.$parent.$watch('property', function(value){/* ... */});`  .... You could also try broadcasting an event instead..

Comment: if selections is an array of objects you need to deep watch it, add true as a 3rd parameter

Answer (score 0):

I figured the this out. Needed to run scope.$apply() after setting the variable with data. Reason scope was not listening was because I was setting the scope from within a jQuery function.

```
            link : function( scope, elem, attrs ){
            //on select change get the attribute selections
            elem.find( "select" ).on( "change", function( vent ){
                var select, option, attribute_id, selections;                   
                select = angular.element( this );
                option = select.find( "option:selected" );      
                attribute_id = parseInt( option.val() );    
                //get the selections off array      
                scope.selections = _.first( 
                    _.where( scope.options, { id : attribute_id }) 
                ).selections;
                //!!APPLY!!!!
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
```